# Taylor Series of $\ln(1+x^3)/[\tan(x)-x]$

Tags: real-analysis

Hi i want to find the Taylor series of the function $$\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{[\tan(x)-x]}$$ at $0$ until n=3

i have $\ln(1+x^3)=x^3-\frac{x^6}{2}+\frac{x^9}{3}+o(x^9)$ and $\tan(x)-x=\frac13 x^3+o(x^3)$

by devision I found that $$\frac{\ln(1+x^3)}{\tan(x)-x}=3-\frac{3}{2}x^3+o(x^3)$$

but I don't find the same result as [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bln%281%2Bx%5E3%29%5D%2F%28tan%28x%29-x%29++Taylor+series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use more terms in the expansion of $\tan x-x$:
\begin{align*}
& \frac{{\log (1 + x^3 )}}{{\tan x - x}} = \frac{{x^3  - \frac{{x^6 }}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^9 )}}{{\frac{1}{3}x^3  + \frac{2}{{15}}x^5  + \mathcal{O}(x^7 )}} = \frac{{3 - \frac{3}{2}x^3  + \mathcal{O}(x^6 )}}{{1 + \frac{2}{5}x^2  + \mathcal{O}(x^4 )}}
\\ &
 = \left( {3 - \frac{3}{2}x^3  + \mathcal{O}(x^6 )} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{2}{5}x^2  + \mathcal{O}(x^4 )} \right) = 3 - \frac{6}{5}x^2  - \frac{3}{2}x^3  + \mathcal{O}(x^4 ).
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you, please what do you think about the methods where you find  the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{(\tan(x)-x)}$ after that multiply it by the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x^3)$ can you help me

Comment: $1/(\tan x-x)$ does not have a Taylor series but a Laurent series around $x=0$.

Comment: so we can't do it in this case where they need a Taylor series ?@Gary

Comment: The best you can do is to write $$
\frac{{\log (1 + x^3 )}}{{x^3 }} \cdot \frac{{x^3 }}{{\tan x - x}}.
$$ Then each of the two factors has a Taylor series around $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

You divide the expansion of $ \ln(1+x^3)$ which begins by $ x^3$,

by the denominator which begins by $ x^3$

So, the numetator should be develpped at order $6$.

the first term of the division starts with $ 1$, thus, the denominator should be expanded untill order $5$.

$$\huge{\frac{x^3-\frac{x^6}{2}+o(x^6)}{\frac{x^3}{3}+...x^5+o(x^6)}}$$

Answer (score 0):

In fact the issue is that you simply divided by $x^3$ anf forgot the $o()$ stuff.

This should be $\frac1{x^3}\times \frac 1{1+o(1)}=\frac 1{x^3}\times(1-o(1))$

All resulting terms smaller than $3\times o(1)=o(1)$ should be ignored in calculation below:

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{x^3-\frac 12x^6+\frac 13x^3+o(x^3)}{\frac 13 x^3+o(x^3)} &=\dfrac{3-\frac 32x^3+x^6+o(x^6)}{1+o(1)}=\left(3-\frac 32x^3+x^6+o(x^6)\right)\times(1-o(1))\\\\
&\require{cancel}=3-o(1)-\cancel{\frac 32x^3}+\cancel{o(x^3)}+\cancel{x^6}-\cancel{o(x^6)}+\cancel{o(x^6)}-\cancel{o(x^6)}\\\\&=3+o(1)\end{align}$

So to keep a development up to $o(x^3)$ you need to keep at least this degree on the denominator after division by $x^3$, this means up to $o(x^6)$ while developing $(\tan x-x)$.